# Equal number of $n$th roots of unity within character values $f_1(a), \dots, f_m(a)$. (Apostol exercise 6.12 Intro to ANT)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, roots-of-unity

This problem is taken from Exercise 6.12 from Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory".

Verbatim, the problem states

> Let $f_1, \dots, f_m$ be the characters of a finite group $G$ of order $m$, and let $a$ be an element of $G$ of order $n$. *Theorem 6.7* shows that each number $f_r(a)$ is an $n$th root of unity. Prove that every $n$th root of unity occurs equally often among the numbers $f_1(a), f_2(a), \dots, f_m(a)$.

Theorem 6.7 above simply states that every $f_r(a)$ is an $n$th root of unity.

The case of $n = 1$ is trivial, I'll assume $n > 1$ throughout the rest of this question. Apostol gives as a hint that evaluation of the sum

$$\sum_{r=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n f_r(a^k) e^{-2\pi ik/n}$$

in "two different ways" shows how many $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i/n}$. The sum above evaluates to $m$, since

$$S = \sum_{r=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n f_r(a^k) e^{-2\pi ik/n} = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{-2\pi ik/n} \sum_{r=1}^m f_r(a^k), $$

and, by Theorem 6.13,

$$\sum_{r=1}^m f_r(a^k) = \begin{cases}
m & k = n \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Therefore, $S$ vanishes for $k = 1, 2, \dots, n-1$, which implies $S = me^{-2\pi i} = m$.

The "second way" to evaluate $S$ is to notice that the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n [f_r(a)e^{-2\pi i/n}]^k$$

equals $n$ only when $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i/n}$, otherwise, $f_r(a)e^{-2\pi i/n}$ is some non-one $n$th root of unity $\omega$ and the sum above equals

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \omega^k = 0$$

by properties of roots of unity. Thus, since $S = m$, if $\alpha$ represents the number of $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i/n}$, then $m = \alpha n$, or $\alpha  =m/n$.

**However**, what would lead one to consider the sum $S$ in the first place? Where did it come from? It seems almost as if $S$ appeared out of "thin air". Is there another way to prove this statement without the evaluation of $S$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the downvote? This seems a reasonable question. What am I missing?

Comment: Why does a 'finite group' of order $m$ have $m$ irreducible characters? Is $G$ abelian here?

Comment: I'm not sure what an irreducible character is, but $G$ can be any group here. According to Apostol, a character on a group $G$ is a complex-valued function $f$ for which $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b \in G$ and $f(c) \neq 0$ for some $c \in G$. It was proven that all values of $f$ are roots of unity.

Comment: Apostol may have been a bit sloppy there, or he may have stated somewhere that only abelian groups are considered. Since characters (as considered in the book, not if "character" means the trace of a representation) factor through the abelianisation $G/[G,G]$, there are fewer than $m$ characters if $G$ isn't abelian.

Comment: So this is what's sometimes called the 'character group' of a finite group $G$. It is equal to the character group of $G/G'$, so we may as well assume that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I have a very basic understanding of groups. I'm assuming $G' = [G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup. How is it that we can assume $G$ is "basically abelian", and how is the character group of $G$ the same as that of $G/G'$? I'm very confused, because there is a specific theorem (6.8) Apostol proves in which he shows that a group of order $m$ has $m$ unique characters. Could there be something possibly invalid with his proof?

Comment: The character group of $G$ is isomorphic as a group to the group $G/G'$, and it often called the *dual group* of $G$. Every degree $1$ character (called a character by Apostol, there are others) is a homomorphism, and the kernel contains $G'$. Thus every character of $G$ is a character of $G/G'$. You cannot obtain any information about the commutator subgroup by looking at (Apostol's definition of) characters.

Comment: As to every finite group having exactly $|G|$ many distinct characters, that's definitely false if $G$ is not abelian. So either Apostol's proof is wrong (unlikely) or there's a global assumption that all groups are abelian.

Comment: OK, I'm going to make this a separate comment, because it's important. The title of Chapter 6 in Apostol is literally '**Finite Abelian Groups and Their Characters**'.

Comment: You're right! There was an assumption that $G$ was abelian in the theorem statement. I suppose then that $G$ must be abelian here too, since the exercise insinuates that $G$ has $m$ distinct characters. I must have overlooked it, my bad.

Comment: My guess as to why he came up with this is that he's doing number theory, and this means he's thinking about Fourier transforms. This sum is obtained by taking the function $g(a^k)=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}k/n}$ and taking the Fourier transform of this with respect to all characters, then taking their sum.

Comment: Is there a more elementary method to obtain the sum mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I gave an elementary method to obtain the same result, that does not involve a double sum, or any sum at all, in the answer. As it's just one way to prove it, I can't simplfy his proof without coming up with a different one.

Comment: I haven't learned Fourier transforms yet either. I was hoping there was something like a combinatoric argument to the sum. If you can't find any, that's alright.

Comment: I've edited my answer to only use concepts from Apostol, and also basic complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof, using only facts from Chapter 6 of Apostol, and using its notation. Let $a\in G$ have order $n$.

The characters form a group under multiplication. Therefore, if $f_1,\dots,f_r$ are the characters, then multiplying by $f_i$ simply permutes the characters. In particular, for any fixed $a\in G$, it permutes the values in the set
$$X=\{f_j(a)\mid 1\leq j\leq r\}.$$
This is the set we wish to prove is simply each $n$th root of unity appearing $r/n$ times. Suppose that $f_i(a)$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity. Then multiplying by $f_i$ has the effect of multiplying all elements in the set $X$ by $f_i(a)$, a primitive $n$th root of unity. The only way such a multiplication can preserve $X$ is if $X$ is uniform.

Thus we must check that there is such an element $f_i$. If not, then all of the $f_j(a)$ (since it is closed under multiplication as the $f_i$ form a group) must be all $m$th roots of unity for some $m$ strictly dividing $n$ (as they are already $n$th roots of unity).

But now, $a^{n/m}$ is a non-trivial element, and $f_i(a^{n/m})=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$. By Theorem 6.10 from Apostol (column orthogonality relation), $a^{n/m}$ is the identity, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the rewording!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a means to build up to the sum Apostol hints at without changing the method of proof wildly or without mentioning techniques beyond that of a pre calculus level.

Consider the sequence $g_r = f_r(a)e^{-2\pi i /n}$. Note that $g_r = 1$ only when $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i /n}$. Otherwise, since $f_r(a)$ is some $n$th root of unity, $g_r$ would be some root of unity not equal to $1$. In a way, $g_r$ represents a sort of indicator function. However, we cannot really distinguish between the roots of unity (that is, we can't really do much with only $g_r$, I think).

In order to make $g_r$ more applicable to the problem, sum over its $n$ powers:

$$G_r = \sum_{k=1}^n g_r^k$$

in order to utilize the property that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \omega^k = \begin{cases}
n & \omega = 1 \\
0 & \omega \neq 1,
\end{cases}$$

where $\omega$ is an $n$th root of unity.

The newly defined $G_r$ is more revealing in terms of the value of $g_r$, and since $g_r$ is an $n$th root of unity,

$$G_r = \begin{cases}
n & g_r = 1 \\
0 & g_r \neq 1,
\end{cases}$$

from which it can be ascertained that

$$G_r = \begin{cases}
n & f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i/n} \\
0 & f_r(a) \neq e^{2\pi i/n}.
\end{cases}$$

Summing $G_r$ over $1 \leq r \leq m$ yields that

$$\sum_{r=1}^m G_r = n\alpha,$$

where $\alpha$ is the number of times $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i /n}$. In fact, the sum above is $S$ as defined in my post.

I personally think that this is intuitive enough without more intense jargon and concepts that I haven't learned yet. However, I think such a line of reasoning may have been the initial intuition of the final sum (although I personally think the sum Apostol gives may have been too revealing, I wanna have fun struggling!!)

To complete the proof, generalize $g_r(t) = f_r(a)e^{-2\pi i t/n}$ and define everything that follows similarly to show that the number of $f_r(a) = e^{2\pi i t/n}$ equals $\alpha(t)$, where

$$S(t) = m = n\alpha(t).$$